# MissingMethodException Plugin CRM2011

Tags: c#, exception, dynamics-crm-2011, missingmethodexception

I found a couple of suggestions on this question but I can't get it on my problem.

We got a .ddl which replaces placeholders in a word file and returned a memorystream. This works fine in a deliverd Test Application with a WPF FrontEnd.

Now we need this solution in a CRM2011 context. I added a reference to this .dll file in my CRM Project, build the logic exactly the way as seen in the example and *boom* a MissingMethodException appears.

I debuged to the point where the Exception is thrown and found somethine like this:

```
    readonly Dictionary<Type, object> typeMap = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

/// <summary>
/// Returns an instance of the DataService implementing the <typeparamref name="TService"/> interface
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TService">type of the interface for the DataService</typeparam>
/// <returns></returns>
public TService For<TService>()
{
  if (typeMap.ContainsKey(typeof(TService)))
  {
    object value = typeMap[typeof(TService)];
    if (value is Type)
    {
      return (TService)Activator.CreateInstance((Type)typeMap[typeof(TService)]);
    }

    return (TService)value;
  }

  return Activator.CreateInstance<TService>();
}
```

The line Activator.CreateInstance(); throws the Exception. I have absolutely no idea what is going wrong here and why this piece of code works fine on the test app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's because you are either attempting to create a Static class, or a class without an empty constructor.  Add try catch that displays the type that is attempting to be created to narrow down what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have a look at this :)